# deploy qbsdk application using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

i created a windows form application in VS2010 using QBSDK.

my problem is that the target has QB installed and running, but i get an error when trying to deploy my one-click application. (the error is just that the application generated an error - and i cannot find the log file to see what actually happened).

to solve it, If i install the QBSDK onto the target machine, it runs fine.

My question is:
what do i need to include in my deployment so i DONT have to install the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the SDK redistributable components for any application that uses the SDK to work. If you are using QBFC, RDS or the QBO connector, there are only two supported ways to distribute these components:
1. You can use the stand-alone compressed-image installers that Intuit provides.
2. You can use the merge modules that Intuit provides.

I don't use ClickOnce deployment, but I think that if you are using ClickOnce deployment you can not include merge modules. I think there's a way to create a custom prerequisite that will install using the stand alone installer; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28VS.80%29.aspx

If you don't want to go that route, you would need to use another deployment option. In Visual Studio 2010, you can create a Visual Studio Installer Setup Project that you can add the merge modules into. This project type is NOT available in the Express editions of Visual Studio, though.

There is a section in the QBSDK Programmer's Guide that gives some more details about deploying the SDK with your application.

Comment: ahhh that makes some sense unfortunately... It is not the end of the world installing the SDK, just wanted to keep the project *trim*.  Thanks for the response!